# Login to another website with javascript and jquery, Send POST to login

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replicate a python code that works, this is the python code I am Trying to replicate

```
        def login(self, username, password):
        print('Logging In...')
        # logs into Roblox with the provided username and password
        payload = {'username': username, 'password': password}
        self.session.post('https://www.roblox.com/newlogin', data=payload)
        print('Successfully Logged In.')
```

Now, I tried to use Jquery post to simulate the same POST, but it keeps erroring. I would like this to also be in one script with no help from any other resources so basically a standalone. This is my current code.

```
var user,pass;
data = {'username': user,'password': pass};

function post(url){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("[*] POST Successfully!");
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("[*] POST Fail!");
    }
});
}
function send(){

  user = prompt("Username:");
  pass = prompt("Password:");

  post(hookurl);
}
send()
```

The website i'm trying to log into (obviously) is https://www.roblox.com/newlogin

Answer (score 0):

javascript CAN NOT post to `cross origin` website, if you want to do this, you have to get admission from the website, like `access-control-allow-origin` header must be defined in the response headers.